# preventing a numericupdown from going passed a certain number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So i want to be able to prevent people increasing the number in a numericupdown after an assigned point is met.

e.g. in rugby the amount of conversions cant be larger then the amount of tries. so say i assigned one numericupdown as tries and had it at 4 then another as conversions. how do i limit so people cant put in anymore then 4 tries.

At the moment i have have `NumericUpDowncon.Maximum = try`
but it still allows the user to input more conversions then tries but then when the calculate button is pressed it puts the converions back down to the max it could be in reguards to the tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a handler to the ValueChanged event of both NumericUpDowns. In the handler you'll have to check if conversions > tries.

```
Private Sub NumericUpDowncon_ValueChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles NumericUpDowncon.ValueChanged, NumericUpDowntry.ValueChanged

   If NumericUpDowncon.Value > NumericUpDowntry.Value then NumericUpDowncon.Value = NumericUpDowntry.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. Btw you forgot the .value on the tries `If NumericUpDowncon.Value > NumericUpDowntry.value then NumericUpDowncon.Value = NumericUpDowntry.value`

Comment: Ok, good to here it worked for you, and I fixed the code too ^^